# how to retrieve a substring from a string?

Tags: iphone

I am doing Fconnect in that when a user connects to facebook I get a string like this
`{"id":"100001480456987","name":"Vishnu Gupta","first_name":"Vishnu","last_name":"Gupta","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100001480456987","education":[{"school":{"id":"110885222265513","name":"st.joseph"},"type":"High School"}],"gender":"male","email":"vishu.gupta20@gmail.com","timezone":5.5,"locale":"en_US","verified":true,"updated_time":"2010-11-27T10:10:25+0000"}`

Now I want to split the id name and email id of the user so that I can store it in my database.

Can someone tell me how to do it????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to split a string to get those values. Instead, you want to parse the JSON to grab data. I've used this library, it works very well: http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Some sample code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [responseFromFacebook JSONValue];
NSString *facebookID = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *email = [dict objectForKey:@"email"];
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks like JSON. Some information on JSON handling with Objective C is available at
http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424253/whats-the-best-way-to-get-data-from-php-to-an-ios-app/4441231#4441231) for links to stackoverflow questions about the different JSON libraries available.

Of course I'd also like to mention my own JSON parsing library, [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).  At the time of this writing I think it's fair to say that it's the fastest JSON parser out there.

Comment: [json-benchmarks](https://github.com/samsoffes/json-benchmarks), [What's the most efficient way of converting a 10 MB JSON response into an NSDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351930/whats-the-most-efficient-way-of-converting-a-10-mb-json-response-into-an-nsdicti), [Cocoa JSON parsing libraries, part 2](http://psionides.jogger.pl/2010/12/12/cocoa-json-parsing-libraries-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
    string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
    string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    NSArray *seperated=[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for(int index=0;index<[seperated count];index++)
    {
        NSArray *sub=[[seperated objectAtIndex:index] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        [dict setValue:[sub objectAtIndex:0] forKey:[sub objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
```