# best JSON parser up to now in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I know that there's a bunch of question like this already, but I would like to know what is currently the best JSON parser out there that is easy to use with objective-C? I also know that apple is pretty strict with accepting codes with third-party code (like the JSON parser), so I want to know what do they accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

I think Apple has accepted so many apps that uses this framework.

BTW, I think third party codes are OK as long as the license says so. Usually if it's BSD or MIT license you're good to go. The framework that I linked to uses BSD.

Comment: Google says:

403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL /p/json-framework/ from this server. That’s all we know.

Why? I'm in China mainland btw.

Comment: I got that too. I don't know why. Has been working for me up until now. This seems to be a fork of that project: https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Answer (score 2):

What's the criteria for "best"?  If "best" means "fastest", then I think [JSONKit](http://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) qualifies (full disclosure: I'm the author of [JSONKit](http://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)).  As far as I know, it is strictly [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) (the JSON RFC) conforming, and if it isn't, file a bug.  :)

- [What's the most efficient way of converting a 10 MB JSON response into an NSDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351930/whats-the-most-efficient-way-of-converting-a-10-mb-json-response-into-an-nsdicti)
- [Cocoa JSON parsing libraries, part 2](http://psionides.jogger.pl/2010/12/12/cocoa-json-parsing-libraries-part-2/)
- [Benchmarks of various JSON frameworks on iOS](https://github.com/samsoffes/json-benchmarks)

Answer (score 1):

i've used yajl-objc successfully. https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc